# Persistent the Current Session Regardless of Page Reload

Tags: php, session, persistence, refresh

So I have `index.php (root)` that user submits a form, it regenerates a session_id on load of the page and stored in hidden input.

Upon entering the data in the `root index.php` file, they are sent to a `profile page`, which has:

```
session_start(); // Bring in old sessionID
$sess_id = session_id();

// If no sessionID redirect back home.
if(empty($sess_id)) {
  header('Location: ../index.php');   
}

// If don't enter, then reload page, redirect back home
elseif(empty($_POST['firstNm']) || empty($_POST['lastNm'])) {
  header('Location: ../index.php');   
}

// If sessionID first send off this data inputted from ../index.php then regenerate session id and update db
else {  
  // Connect to db
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = 'SiteRoot/';
  // Grabs a new user's : username, pass, email from default [index.php] once submitted
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'cfg/'.'dbi.php');
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'registration/'.'inituserCredentialsGrab.php');

  // After submitting original values, update new session ID in database since original was viewable via source hidden inputs
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'registration/'.'newUserSessIDInitReg.php');
}
```

This file basically gets all the initial input. Gets the initial session_id which is visible by viewing source... and regenerates it. After regenerating it submits to the db.

The problem is, if I go to `RELOAD` the page, it seems to regenerate the id again. How do I fix this, so that no matter how many times I refresh during the current browser session it doesn't do the `regenerate_id`?

Answer (score 0):

I would store in my new session a flag that the id has already been regenerated and check that whenever coming into the page.

For example:

```
session_start(); // Bring in old sessionID              
$sess_id = session_id();              

// If no sessionID redirect back home.              
if(empty($sess_id)) {              
  header('Location: ../index.php');                 
}              

// If don't enter, then reload page, redirect back home              
elseif(empty($_POST['firstNm']) || empty($_POST['lastNm'])) {              
  header('Location: ../index.php');                 
}              

// If sessionID first send off this data inputted from ../index.php then regenerate session id and update db              
elseif(!isset($_SESSION['already_stored'])){                
  // Connect to db              
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = 'SiteRoot/';              
  // Grabs a new user's : username, pass, email from default [index.php] once submitted              
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'cfg/'.'dbi.php');              
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'registration/'.'inituserCredentialsGrab.php');              

  // After submitting original values, update new session ID in database since original was viewable via source hidden inputs              
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'registration/'.'newUserSessIDInitReg.php');
  $_SESSION['already_stored'] = true;
}
```

If the code for updating the database still needs to run on every reload, then you can move the if condition to only surround the regeneration of the session id itself.